Is there any reference where Roger Penrose addresses the "effective size" of the mass density in a neutron star which must be at least 100 fermis?
The background is the following. Roger Penrose has proposed that a spatial quantum superposition collapses because of gravity. To put in a nutshell, the probability of quantum collapse per unit of time of a system in quantum superposition is related to the gravitational potential energy of this system. The collapse induces a production of heat. The amount of heat thus produced depends in a crucial way on the effective mass density of the particles involved. The higher the density, the higher the production of heat.
Further, R. Penrose has proposed that the effective mass density should be related to the width of the stationary Schrödinger equation that describes the particles. For instance, in his paper
On the gravitization of quantum mechanics 1: Quantum State Reduction Found. Phys. 44, 557 (2014)
I found the following sentence

What we need to do is first to solve the stationary Schrödinger equation for the material in our object.

It is further explained that what he means is to factor off the mass center and consider only the Schrödinger equation describing the wave function relative to the mass center.
In the paper
Neutron star heating constraints on wave-function collapse models, A. Tilloy and M. T. State, Phys. Rev. Lett 123, 080402 (2019)
it is shown that if the effective density in a neutron star in the so-called Diósi-Penrose model were related to its size, of the order of a fermi ($10^{-15}$m), neutron stars would be much hotter than they are. To allow for the lowest temperature measured for a neutron star, namely the object called PSR J 840-1419, the effective density should be related to a size about 100 times larger. And this is only a lower bound, since there might well be neutron stars even cooler, the temperatures of which have not yet been measured.
But the particle density in a neutron star is roughly of the order of one neutron per cubic fermi (more like 0.4 neutrons per cubic fermi but this is a not a large correction).
So my question is:
Is there any reference where Penrose or any supporter of his "objective reduction" approach has addressed the question of how the effective width of the stationary solution to the Schrödinger equation for the material in our object, namely neutrons, could be of the order of 100 fermis, corresponding do an effective mass density about 400,000 times less than the actual mass density of a neutron star?

I can't find any direct comment on the paper about heating of neutron stars, or any of the other calculations which constrain the rate of spontaneous collapse. But here are some recent quotes:

"... the two theories are often called the “Diósi-Penrose” (DP) theory in the literature. Behind the joint name DP, there is a particular difference. Unlike Penrose’s approach, which lacks general dynamics, Diósi’s general dynamics predicts violations of energy conservation that are appreciable enough to be experimentally tested and constrained. Indeed Penrose has expressed to us that he regards this feature of the DP theory as unphysical, expects it to be definitively ruled out by future experiments, and seeks a physical theory of gravity-related wave function collapse that avoids this (in his view) unphysical feature of energy conservation violation. Equally dissatisfied is Diósi, thinking about new collapse dynamics to ensure energy-momentum conservation." -- Derakhshani et al, 2022


"D[iósi]-OR predicts detectable radiation due to diffusion of charged particles; P[enrose]-OR predicts no detectable radiation. Penrose has proposed that OR events have retroactive effects which ‘go back in time’ to get rid of the unselected curvature and prevent detectable radiation." -- Hameroff, 2023

So both Penrose and Diósi want to find an energy-conserving dynamics, which would presumably eliminate the heating entirely.
In browsing the broader literature, I have also noticed claims that heating might be reduced by modifying the probability distribution. For example, Derakhshani et al above hints at "non-Markovian" modifications of "DP collapse dynamics". But I don't have a specific equation to show you what that could mean.
Here, incidentally, is the latest theoretical work by Penrose on this subject, coauthored with twistor theorist Maciej Dunajski: "Quantum state reduction, and Newtonian twistor theory" (2023).

Thank you very much. I have another 5 days to grant the bounty. I'll wait a while for the case I get an even better answer, otherwise I'll accept yours.

Clearly there won't be any better answer !
